# Declaring type parameter twice in Collections objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, types

I've been learning about Java (using Java 6) and I noticed that when a `Collections` object (say, `ArrayList`) is created, one must declare the type parameter both in the reference type and in the object type. Wouldn't it be easier to just declare the type parameter only in the reference type? Or are there situations where the type parameters can be different?

For example, the type parameter below (`String`) must be declared twice.

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Yes, it would.  That's why that feature was added in Java 7.  (Though, yes, the type parameters can be different, e.g. `List<? extends Object>` on the LHS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 7 also introduced the ["diamond" form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), which infers the type and lets you write less verbose code.

> If the type argument list to the class is empty — the diamond form
>   "<>" — the type arguments of the class are inferred. It is legal,
>   though strongly discouraged as a matter of style, to have white space
>   between the "<" and ">" of a diamond.

So, you can write:

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

There are a few examples [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained **Static constructors**:

Before JDK 7, constructing new generic collections requires unpleasant code duplication:

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = new ArrayList<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood>();
```

I think we can all agree that this is unpleasant. Guava provides static methods that use generics to infer the type on the right side:

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = Lists.newArrayList();
Map<KeyType, LongishValueType> map = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
```

To be sure, the diamond operator in JDK 7 makes this less of a hassle:

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = new ArrayList<>();
```